# Extract the content from a file between two unique tags or comments and put it into other file with same tags or comments?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I have 2 files **test1.py** and **test2.py** with this content

**test1.py :**

```
#first

#endoffirst

#second

#endofsecond

#3rd

#endof3rd
```

and **test2.py :**

```
#first
this is first command
#endoffirst

#second
this is second command
#endofsecond

#3rd
this is 3rd command
#endof3rd
```

I want to first check **test2.py** file and copy content between **#first** and **#endoffirst** and put it into the same tags in **test1.py** file with bash scripting or other operations in Linux. I mean that all content between two unique tags or commands in one file should copy and put in between the same tags or comments in other file.

I already test so many things line **sed** command but I can't get the right answer.

I appreciate that anyone can help me whit this

Comment: I think you have to ***think associative array*** if you want to do this in [tag:bash]... `1):` list of uniq tags, `2):` Content of tags, `3):` Order of tags, `4):` Re-Create file1 by following tags in file1.

Comment: This look like a *homework*?!

Comment: @F.Hauri no I have to make some code snippets in GitLab and need to merge files with the same name but I need to put new coming codes in unique places in files. for example In local files i have setting.py but when i fetch new setting i need replace some new codes in local one

Comment: U said: *``I already test so many things..''*, please share!

Comment: @F.Hauri I try sed and diff command. first I was comparing two files with diff command and after that new file include all new stuff from the second file and after that I try to delete extra things between tags using sed like this `sed "/#first/,/endoffirst/d" setting.py >newsetting.py && mv newsetting.py setting.py
` but I had some unknown errors after doing this.

Comment: If `cp test2.py test1.py` isn't all you need (and I don't think it is but it'd produce the expected output from your posted sample input which demonstrates that your sample input isn't adequate to cover your requirements)  then [edit] your question to show more truly representative sample input including cases of tags that exist in test1.py but not in test2.py and vice-versa and show the output you'd expect given those input files.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use `sed`, I'd do it in two passes.

```
sed -n '/#first/,/#endoffirst/w tmp' test2.py
sed '/#first/,/#endoffirst/{
       /#endoffirst/!d;
       /#endoffirst/{ z; r tmp
     } }' test1.py

#first
this is first command
#endoffirst

#second

#endofsecond

#3rd

#endof3rd
```

The weird formatting is because if you use `r` (or `w`) then the filename has to be the only thing on the rest of the line. Semicolons, spaces, closing curlies or pretty much anything else but a newline will be included in the filename by `sed`.

I'd probably use `awk`. Here's a clumsy pass at that.

```
$: awk '/#first/,/#endoffirst/{
         if (NR == FNR) { x=x$0; if ($0 ~ "#endoffirst") { nextfile } else { x=x"\n" } }
         else           {        if ($0 ~ "#endoffirst") { print x; } }
         next } {print}' test2.py test1.py
#first
this is first command
#endoffirst

#second

#endofsecond

#3rd

#endof3rd
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^#/ {
    inBlock = !inBlock
    if ( inBlock ) {
        tag = $0
    }
}
NR == FNR {
    if ( inBlock ) {
        val[tag] = (tag in val ? val[tag] ORS : "") $0
    }
    next
}
$0 in val {
    print val[$0]
}
!inBlock
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk test2.py test1.py
#first
this is first command
#endoffirst

#second
this is second command
#endofsecond

#3rd
this is 3rd command
#endof3rd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import fdopen, remove
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import copymode, move

try:
    start_flag_count = end_flag_count = 0
    content_dict = {}
    with open('/tmp/test2.py') as old_file:
        for line in old_file:
            ori_line = line
            line = line.strip()
            if line and line.startswith('#'):    # change '#' for your tags startswith
                if start_flag_count == end_flag_count:
                    cur_tag = line
                    start_flag_count += 1
                    mul_content_lines = ''
                elif start_flag_count == end_flag_count + 1:
                    content_dict[cur_tag] = mul_content_lines
                    end_flag_count += 1
            else:
                if start_flag_count == end_flag_count + 1:
                    mul_content_lines += ori_line

    ori_file = '/tmp/test1.py'
    fd, tmp_file_path = mkstemp()
    with fdopen(fd, 'w') as new_file:
        with open(ori_file) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                new_file.write(line)
                line = line.strip()
                if line and line.startswith('#') and line in content_dict:
                    new_file.write(content_dict[line])
    copymode(ori_file, tmp_file_path)
    remove(ori_file)
    move(tmp_file_path, ori_file)
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

Run in `Python 2.7`, firstly, get the unique tags content and save it to dictionary with start flag by reading test2.py; then scan test1.py and add the content by tag after the start flag line.